# CrossMediaManager MediaItemFinished gives playing status instead of stop in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am playing audio files from device library using [CrossMediaManager](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager) plugin. It plays files correctly, however, in `MediaitemFinised`instead of `stopped` status I am getting `playing` status. What I am trying to achieve is to play another file or stop playing based on some settings. e.g If user setting is configured to play next, I am picking another file and playing next item, but I need to do that after playing the first item is fully finished.

```
    void AddCrossMediaHandlers()
    {
       CrossMediaManager.Current.StateChanged += Current_StateChanged;
       CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaItemFinished += Current_MediaItemFinished;
       CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaPlayer.BeforePlaying += MediaPlayer_BeforePlaying;
    }
    void RemoveCrossMediaHandlers()
    {
       CrossMediaManager.Current.StateChanged -= Current_StateChanged;
       CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaItemFinished -= Current_MediaItemFinished;
       CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaPlayer.BeforePlaying -= MediaPlayer_BeforePlaying;
    }
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartPlaying(someFilePath);
    }
    async void StartPlaying(filePath)
    {
       var player = CrossMediaManager.Current;
       if (player.State != MediaManager.Player.MediaPlayerState.Playing)
       {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
               await player.Play(new FileInfo(filePath));
       }
    }
    private void Current_MediaItemFinished(object sender, MediaManager.Media.MediaItemEventArgs e)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine("item Finished event: " + CrossMediaManager.Current.State); //this return playing status therefore it doesen't play the next file.
//When media is finished look for user setting and play next or stop playing.
       if (playNext) //I also checked !CrossMediaManager.Current.IsPlaying(), but didn't help.
          StartPlaying(NextFilePath); //This fire, but because the status is playing, it doesn't play next.
    }
```

Comment: Got it working, added 1 second delay in MediaItemFinished after calling await player.Stop();

Comment: Hi , if have solved that , remember to update solution in answer when you have time. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. In case someone else may need it. I added Task.Delay(milliseconds) to wait for the player to stop.

```
private void Current_MediaItemFinished(object sender, MediaManager.Media.MediaItemEventArgs e)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine("item Finished event: " + CrossMediaManager.Current.State); //this return playing status therefore it doesen't play the next file.
       var player = CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaPlayer;
       await player.Stop(); //stop playing explicitly
       await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // add a delay (you can add milliseconds)
    }
```